# Slow download speeds from Copernicus?

Tags: import, linux, copernicus, sentinel-hub, sentinel-5p

I'm downloading Sentinel 3 and 5p data using the dhusget.sh script provided here:

https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/do/view/SciHubUserGuide/BatchScripting?redirectedfrom=SciHubUserGuide.8BatchScripting#Query_via_wget

While it works, it is very slow, and downloads data at roughly 1mbps on my 100mbps network. Is this a solvable problem, or is it like this for everyone?